# missing folders from dynamic site

Tags: php, directory

Ok, the project is up and running for almost 2 years now.
Purpose is to have a complete list of painters and their paintings.

Admin can create new painter and then upload paintings to that painter.
Each painter has its own folder, where the images are saved.
And each photo is saved into its own sub-folder.
All of these are stored in a single folder

So, in root folder, there is the folder named "artists" where everything is stored
If a painter has 10 paintings, the script will create:
[artist_name] folder inside "artists" folder
in [artist_name] it will create 11 folders. 10 for each painting plus a thumbs folder to save the thumbs.

So, in the end it look like this

```
/artist/
|--->painter1
   |--->folder1
   |--->folder2
   |--->folder3
   .....
   |--->thumbs
|--->painter2
 .....
```

I hope this makes seance - Don't ask why each photo is saved into a different folder, its irrelevant with my problem.

As i said this is up and running for almost 2 years now.
In the last 20 days or so, every time the administrator is trying to add a new painter or upload a new painting into the system, a random folder gets deleted - and i mean a painter's folder.

First thought was the site was hacked. I searched the files for suspicious code, I found none, but just to be sure I uploaded my backups, and yet no results. The problem continues.

I must tell you that the main folder "artist" has 1006 main folders inside it and in total there are more than 17000 subfolders in the 1006 folders.
The website runs in MySQL 5.0.77, PHP 5.2.17, Apache 2.2.3

Has anyone any idea as to why this is happening?

Comment: Need to see the upload code and the code where you add a new painter.

Comment: stereofrog, the folders are php created. In the logs i haven't found anything i can use - other than lots of missing files (jpg) that are produced from the deleted files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I think:

- Not a problem with your code, as the system has been running for 2 years
- Not a problem with hackers, as you've checked and uploaded a backup one
- Not a problem with the server's installed software.

So probably, it might probably be a problem with the operating system (or the drives), in which it doesn't allow more folders to be created, or it gets nut when a large amount of folders have been created and accessed.

Can you try to cut off some of the folders (maybe the oldest folders) and move them into another file server? As this solution seems limited but if it helps, it should be nice.

Hope this answers your problem.

Comment: So, instead of moving folders into other server, I will move them to another folder. This requires some work, so i will come back later with results. Thank you for the advice